# build a php session handler with neo4j database

Tags: php, session, authentication, neo4j

How can I build a session handler in php that store sessions data in neo4j database?
How can I draw a schema good schema for neo4j for save sessions user data and manage user authentication for a web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a [SessionHandler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandlerinterface.php) instance that uses the Neo4J REST API. There is a [PHP library](https://github.com/jakewins/Neo4j.php) that should cover communicating with Neo4J: as it is a graph database you don't really need to lose sleep over a schema in advance. The session interface just requires you to save/retrieve an associative array: unless you are explicitly planning to browse through the data via some other language you can just serialize it to a string (or to JSON) and store it as a property in a new node keyed by the session id.

Comment: I could create a node per session and user that do login I store data as serialized into node that represent that current session? so then can I search node by sessionId and see if that node has store data serialize of user, so it is authenticate? It is a good approach thus?

Comment: That would work: whenever the user logged in you would set a property on the session node, and whenever they logged out you'd remove that property, and you can just check that as necessary.

Comment: I agree with everything Fermi said, but I would pick the newer Neo4jPHP library (http://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp). If you are looking to use Neo4j from PHP, it's more fully featured, better tested, and is under active development. Disclaimer - I'm the author.